# 左に曲がる/右に曲がる v/s 左折/右折

Tags: word-choice, nuances, wago-and-kango

That's it, essentially. What differentiates these two ways to indicate a turn? 
So far, I had only heard 左に曲がる/右に曲がる, but recently I heard 左折/右折 in the GPS of a car. At first I thought that the latter was just a noun version, more than an action, but I've seen examples where the latter seems to also be used as a する verb (i.e. 自動車は左折した). Is it more car-related? A Google image search for the latter only shows car-driving related pictures.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23156/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/68690/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18365/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13783/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

右折する、左折する refer only to cars, bicycles, busses,  and other vehicles on road (I think airplanes can 右折 while on road, not flying)
右に曲がる 左に曲がる is used in various ways.

> この線は右に曲がっている。
>   コンビニまで歩いたら右に曲がってください。
>   鳥は右に曲がった。

Comment: I see, thank you !